# Simple pagination with twig

Tags: php, loops, pagination, twig

I'm trying to create a simple pagination with a twig view.
I'm not using Symfony.

Here is my method from my manager :

```
  public function getAllPosts()
  {
      if(isset($_GET['p']) && (!isset($_GET['page']))){

          $currentPage =  1;
      }
      else {
          $currentPage = $_GET['page'];
      }
    $q= $this->_db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS numberposts FROM posts');
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $number_posts= $data['numberposts'];
    $perPage = 1;
    $numberPages = ceil($number_posts/$perPage);

    $q = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".(($currentPage-1)*$perPage).",$perPage");

    while($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $datas[] = new Post($data);
    }


    return $datas;

  }
```

I want to create a loop in my view, this is what I'm doing

```
            {% for posts in allPosts %}
               {% for i in 1..numberPages %}
                    <a href="index.php?p=blog&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
                 {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

But it's not working. It seems like I can't access to numberPages and I don't know why.

If anybody can help me !

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

My pagination is working now.

I had this in my method like @darkbee :

```
        return array(
    'records'     => $datas,
    'numberPages' => $numberPages,
);
```

And in my view :

```
{% for i in 1.. allPosts.numberPages %}
                    <li><a href="index.php?p=blog&page{{ loop.index }}">{{ loop.index}}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
```

But now I have another issue. I only get the same posts in all the pages.

**EDIT**

I forgot the page= on my pages links ...

```
 <li><a href="index.php?p=blog&page={{ loop.index }}">{{ loop.index}}</a></li>
```

It's working now !

Thanks !

Comment: nowhere you are returning `numberPages`

Comment: Ok so I've not understand how to return variables with Twig ... I thought that when you render a view with a method, you could access to variables inside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the number of pages as well.
An aproach could be this,

```
public function getAllPosts()  {
    /** ... code .. **/
    return array(
        'records'     => $data,
        'numberPages' => $numberPages,
    );
}



{% for posts in allPosts.records %}
    {% for i in 1.. allPosts.numberPages %}
         <a href="index.php?p=blog&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok thanks I understand now how it's working. Now nothing is displayed, but I'm looking why

Comment: what is 1.. in 1.. allPosts.numberPages. I don't understand this code. can you explain please ??

Comment: @Zakirhussain That is the twig alternative for `<?php for($i = 1; $i < $allPosts.numberPages; $i++) {`